Sql Server Extened Events lock_acquired and lock_released - The meaning of resource_0, resource_1 and resource_2
The lock_acquired and lock_released events have the resource_0, resource_1, resource_2 properties and their content and meaning depends on the resource_type, but their meaning is not always clear to me.
For example, let's create the following XE;
CREATE EVENT SESSION [XE_Demo] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.session_id))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

Then, in SSMS open two sessions.
From Session #1 execute the following script:
--Session #1
drop table if exists t1;
go

create table t1 (
    id int primary key,
    f1 varchar(36));
go

create statistics t1_st_1 on t1(f1);
go

insert into t1 
select gs.value, cast(NEWID() as varchar(36))
from generate_series(1, 1000, 1) gs
;

Now start the Extened Event just created before, activate the "Watch Live Data" window and to keep things clearer, filter the results by session_id(s), mode <> SCH_S and resource_type = OBJECT.
From Session #2 open a transaction, update one row and keep the transaction open:
--Session #2
begin tran;
update t1 
set f1 = 'new value'
where id = 1;

From Session #1 execute the following:
update statistics t1 t1_st_1 with fullscan;

This is what I have in the "Watch Live Data" window:

We have two sessions that acquired IX and X locks on the same resource_0 (the table t1 in this case) but on different resource_1.
What does resource_1 represent?
And more in general what do resource_0, resource_1 and resource_2 represent varying the resource_type?
Thanks in advance.

It means different things for different types of locks. In your case the resource_0 matches the associated_object_id
To parse other types of resources I usually use these posts:

Decoding Key and Page WaitResource for Deadlocks and Blocking by Kendra Little
Documentation for sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks - section resource_description column


Lock resource owner:

<type-specific-description> id=lock<lock-hex-address> mode=<mode>
associatedObjectId=<associated-obj-id>

<type-specific-description> can
be:

For DATABASE: databaselock subresource=<databaselock-subresource>
dbid=<db-id>
For FILE: filelock fileid=<file-id>
subresource=<filelock-subresource> dbid=<db-id>
For OBJECT: objectlock
lockPartition=<lock-partition-id> objid=<obj-id>
subresource=<objectlock-subresource> dbid=<db-id>
For PAGE: pagelock
fileid=<file-id> pageid=<page-id> dbid=<db-id>
subresource=<pagelock-subresource>
For Key: keylock hobtid=<hobt-id>
dbid=<db-id>
For EXTENT: extentlock fileid=<file-id> pageid=<page-id>
dbid=<db-id>
For RID: ridlock fileid=<file-id> pageid=<page-id>
dbid=<db-id>
For APPLICATION: applicationlock hash=<hash>
databasePrincipalId=<role-id> dbid=<db-id>
For METADATA: metadatalock
subresource=<metadata-subresource> classid=<metadatalock-description>
dbid=<db-id>
For HOBT: hobtlock hobtid=<hobt-id>
subresource=<hobt-subresource> dbid=<db-id>
For ALLOCATION_UNIT:
allocunitlock hobtid=<hobt-id> subresource=<alloc-unit-subresource>
dbid=<db-id>


<mode> can be: Sch-S, Sch-M, S, U, X, IS, IU, IX, SIU,
SIX, UIX, BU, RangeS-S, RangeS-U, RangeI-N, RangeI-S, RangeI-U,
RangeI-X, RangeX-, RangeX-U, RangeX-X




These should match the resource_x columns of the Xevent but the ordering might be different. I usually try to sanity check by parsing a known resource.
